# Node unable find the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I was writing some node.js code and integrating frontend and node backend for a simple signup application. But my node is not able to find the signup.html page.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const path = require('path')

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/public'));
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/signup.html');
});

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('Server started at port 3000');
});
```

Comment: You forgot the public folder in your path. `res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/signup.html');`

Comment: Is there a way to make sure that everytime I specify some file my server looks for it at /public folder and not in root directory... like ```res.sendFile('/signup.html');``` should find for signup.html in public folder

Comment: You're trying to solve a problem you don't have; doing this for the `/` route and manually sending back `/public/signup.html` is enough, beyond that you can link the user to for instance `success.html` and the static setup you already have in place takes care of it. If you don't want to just create a static server that serves HTML files, you need to switch to proper routes and views anyway; I recommend using [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) over ejs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `set()` to redefine express's default settings.

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: It's still finding the html file in same level as app.js not in public folder.

Comment: Updated my answer. Working fine tested.